# Snapping to vertex plane while editing in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, editing

Occasionally when I edit a new polygon feature I want to finish one side of it exactly where it meets the plane of an existing vertex of another feature (in order to create a 90 degree angle to that vertex).

This ability exists on AutoCAD (as can be seen in the picture attached), but I haven't found a way to do that on ArcGIS Desktop. I usually work around this problem by making bigger shapes than necessary and then trimming what I don't need.

Anybody know a solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If snapping to an existing vertex is you problem than you want the snapping toolbar and [enable vertex snapping.](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/enabling-snapping.htm)

There are three ways to do right angle line segments.

Use the right [angle tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/creating-a-segment-at-a-right-angle-90-degrees-.htm) from the editing toolbar.

You can just use the [perpandicular constraint](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/creating-a-segment-perpendicular-to-another-segment.htm)

Or you can use the [angle and length](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/creating-a-segment-using-an-angle-and-a-length.htm)